# Adding new element to the object based on the comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following objects:

```
var empAry= [{"empid":"101","name":"David"},{"empid":"102","name":"Sam"}..];//2000 records

var empAry2= [{"empid":"101","name":"David"},{"empid":"105","name":"Kevin"},{"empid":"109","name":"Robert"},{"empid":"110","name":"Rob"}..];//30000 records
```

I need to add new element to the `empAry` object and populate new element value based on the availability of  that particular record in `empAry2`.

**Expected Output:-**

```
empAry= [{"empid":"101","name":"David", **"FounInempAry2":"Yes"**},{"empid":"102","name":"Sam", **"FounInempAry2":"No"}**..];//2000 records
```

If we can do it by jquery that would be good. Please help me.

Comment: can you please share what have you tried so far ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to make sense of what `FounInempAry2` is since the object structures are identical in both samples. I will assume that other properties exist and will use jQuery `$.extend()` to "merge" the properties.

First it is likely most efficient to loop through the big array once and create an object using the `empid` as keys.

```
var tmp = {};
$.each( empAry2, function(_, item){
    tmp[ item.empid ] = item;
});
```

This creates an object like:

```
{ 
    "101" : {"empid":"101","name":"David"},
    "102" : {"empid":"102","name":"Sam"}
}
```

Now loop through first array and extend with whatever is in matching object in the `tmp` object

```
$.each( empAry, function(_, item){
    $.extend( item, tmp[ item.empid ]);
});
```

Reference:  [$.extend() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var entry = {"empid":"<some id>","name":"<some name>"}
var filter = empAry2.filter(function(o){
return o.empid==entry.empid;
});
entry.FounInempAry2=(filter && filter.length>0)?"Yes":"No";
empAry2.push(entry);
```

Or

```
var entry = {"empid":"<some id>","name":"<some name>","FounInempAry2":"No"}
for(var i=0,length=empAry2.length;i<length;i++){
if(empAry2[i].empid==entry.empid){
entry.FounInempAry2="Yes";
break;
}
}
empAry2.push(entry);
```